# WPF binding data from datagrid to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

i'm new to WPF and still learn on it. I create a sample application and connect to the database. After i select data to the database, i can show it into my datagrid. Now, my concern is i want to bind to textbox depends on the row from my datagrid.

so, whenever i click or select row in my datagrid, i bind the value to textbox. i already do some google and tried. but still failed. is there any solution? thanks.

here is my application picture. 
[image]

how is the xaml look like to bind for example row no 3 to my textbox? is there any class i should implement? because in windows form i just need to call cellclick. thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm always binding SelectedItem (datagrid Property) to a Property in my ViewModel. 
And then you can bind the Controls to this property. 
You also can achieve this without a viewmodel only with xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=myDataGrid}"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. thats mean i have to implement a datagrid property in my code .cs, after that i alos change the .xaml? but do you have any sample code? thanks.

Comment: You mentioned that you are new to WPF, so I highly recommend reading on MVVM Pattern (Model View ViewModel). I have added a code example to my answer that uses only xaml

Comment: wait.. i got it.. thanks. How about if we change on the datagrid? i mean instead of bind, we also can change the value inside the datagrid.

Comment: myDataGrid is the name of the datagrid. SelectedItem is a reference to the item that is currently selected in the grid. SelectedItem.Name is a arbitrary chosen Property. You can use any Property that is implemented in the class of the items that you have added to the grid

Comment: now i understand. but how about by clicking the row in my datagrid, i also can edit/type, after that save to my database. is that possible?

Comment: Sure you can, but there are many possibilities to do this. In my projects I am using an ORM (nHibernate) that handles the persistence of my objects. You could also use EntityFramework or directly Ado.net ...

Comment: thanks for your time and answer.. i will search on what you suggest.. thanks. :)